# xcode uitableviewcell options don't include identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to change the identifier of my uitableviewcell in storyboards.  The problem is that options pain doesn't have the option available anymore.  See the image below:

[image]

As you can see the options are limited.  How can I see the full range of options?

Comment: Click on "Table View Cell" to expand the upper pane ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I hover over the Table View Cell menu bar, there is an option to 'Show' which then allows me to set the identifier.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You minimized the area that allows you to edit the identifier and style etc. You need to click on the header called "Table View Cell", and it will expand the options for you. That's happened to me plenty of times. Hope that helps.